# Coproducts for non-small indexed families of morphisms?

Tags: category-theory

It is well-known that a category that has products for all class-indexed families must be thin (i.e. posetal). Does a similar result hold for coproducts?

MY ATTEMPT:

Working with coproduct, I only have that the opposite category is thin. May I infer that also the starting category is thin?

Comment: Yes. The opposite of a thin category is thin. This is easy to prove.